# Include a folder in the repository first time and then ignore from next time onwards

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to do the following thing-

1. I have a folder `config` which I wanted to include to the git repository first time and I could do that without fail.
2. Next, I make a change in `.gitignore` file so that it excludes any changes from that directory by adding

`/config/`

3. Next, I commit the change and update the branch
4. Then I make a change to a file which is under `config` directory but it shows under changed file when I do `git status`

Is there a way so that I can include a folder first time and then tell git to ignore from next time onwards.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Can you provide more detail about why you need to set up your project this way? Possibly there’s another solution, such as keeping a default/sample config and then having a custom config that never goes to source. 2. Have you considered git update-index —skip-worktree? This would work if you’re the sole collab but may be more complex if you have others to explain this to.

Comment: There are thousands of questions about how to save developer-specific configuration files outside of Git. Have you tried reading [ask] and doing research?

Comment: That answer is wrong.  See the [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile) for the answer to this question.

Comment: .gitignore does not work on tracked files. If you added /committed a file, git does not care that you put it in .gitignore, it will notice if you change it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way so that I can include a folder first time and then tell git to ignore from next time onwards.

No: I usually version:

- config file *templates*
- an `init` script which is executed by the user cloning the repository, and generating (if the actual config files do not yet exist) the config files from the template files.

That way:

- the config files remain private (not version)
- they are ignored by the `.gitignore`
- they can be modified as many time as you want.